# Swig output line endings

Tags: swig

I'm running swig using cmake to interface some c++ libraries with java. Was wondering if there was an option to specify the line endings of the java output files generated by swig?

```
set(swig_interface "swig/my_swig.i")

set_source_files_properties("${swig_interface}" PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

set(jni_output "${SWIG_WRAPPER_OUTPUT}/com/domain/group")

# Hoping theres a flag I can add here which will set the line endings
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-package" "com.domain.group"
                     "-I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR "${jni_output}")

swig_add_module(jni_wrapper java "${swig_interface}" ${lib_src_files})
swig_link_libraries(jni_wrapper other_lib)
```

Comment: How is this related to CMake? Share some code how you invoke Swig.

Comment: Added a snapshot of the cmake code I'm using to invoke Swig.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to CMake. This is a Swig-only issue. Concerning Swig: This feature was added in Januar 2015, see https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/540. Once you figured out how to call a recent version of Swig manually, you just add this parameter to your CMake file.

Comment: Yes, I have also read that issue and it seems that fix is for "allowing" crlf in the templates. Whereas the issue I'm having is I want to "choose" the line ending.

Comment: So you say there is no interface for invoking it from outside, right? I guess this is not provided by Swig and you have to open an issue in Swig.